htaccess rewrite for cache busting
In an attempt to cache bust .css and .js files, and not wanting to go the query string route,  I want to, via htaccess rewrite paths that start with "foo*/" to remove/ignore "foo*/" - the asterisk can be any number, as it will be the version.
example #1:
/foo123/css/style.css
should actually just request:
/css/style.css

example #2:
/foo456/js/script.js
should actually request:
/js/script.js

Another way could be to have the version number, to be ignored, in the file name. again, the number can be anything, so it cant be hardcoded, so perhaps it should explode file name, and remove 2nd part.
example:
/css/styles.123.css
should actually just request:
/css/styles.css

or:
/js/script.11235.js
should actually just request:
/js/script.js

So far what i got, which is not working at all, is this, which just gives me a 404:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 [L]

above code is from:
https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/02a601e5914a504e019c46b76bb21adab89cb686/src/.htaccess#L677-692
I currently have this, for pretty urls, so it need to keep in consideration not to break/interfere with this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

grateful for any help,
thanks!

So what is your actual question? "I want" is not a question. You need to implement a rewriting rule for that. Where is it? How do you expect us to help if you do not post your implementation? Keep in mind: we are not a free coding service. You are expected to implement your own solution. You are expected to know the tools you are using. We are only here to help if you fail to get your implementation to work.

my apologies. i have updated what i got since posting the question.

add this for versioned paths:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo\d+/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L]

replace with this for versioned filenames:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.\d+\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]

leave your pretty url entries intact
note: dont forget there will only be one RewriteEngine On in .htaccess

More specific: place above rules before the existing rule rewriting to the index.php router. So between the RewriteEngine on and the sequence of existing RewriteConds and the RewriteRule. The order is important, such configuration files are processed from top to bottom.

@nabin thank you so much, works perfectly both of them. however, small tweak for the version file name rule: what if the folder are /assets/css and /assets/js - i tried adding it to (css|js) part but it broke. i guess its the slashes that interfere.

you need to place assets/(css|js)/ in between first openaing brancket ( and dot . in
RewriteRule for filename.
